# distinct sum does not distinct values

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables, reservations and articles:

**Reservations**

```
------------------------------
Id     |   Name   |     City |
------------------------------
 1     |  Mike    | Stockholm
 2     |  Daniel  | Gothenburg
 2     |  Daniel  | Gothenburg
 3     |  Andre   | Gothenburg (Majorna)
```

**Articles**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
ArticleId    |    Name       |    Amount |    ReservationId | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
10           |   Coconuts    |    1      |    1         
10           |   Coconuts    |    4      |    2     
11           |   Apples      |    2      |    2
12           |   Oranges     |    2      |    3
```

I want to select Articles Name and the sum of Articles.Amount per Articles.ArticleId and Reservations.City.

My code:

```
SELECT distinct r.ID,a.Name as ArticleName,
       sum(a.Amount) as ArticlesAmount,
       substr(r.City,1,3) as ToCityName 
FROM Reservations r 
INNER JOIN Articles a 
      on r.Id = a.ReservationId 
WHERE  a.Name <> '' 
GROUP BY ToCityName,a.ArticleId,a.Name 
ORDER BY ToCityName ASC
```

This gives me following result:

```
Id | ArticleName | ArticlesAmount | ToCityName

2  |  Coconuts   |   8            |   Got 
2  |  Apples     |   4            |   Got 
3  |  Oranges    |   2            |   Got 
1  |  Coconuts   |   1            |   Sto
```

But i want:

```
Id | ArticleName | ArticlesAmount | ToCityName

2  |  Coconuts   |   4            |   Got 
2  |  Apples     |   2            |   Got 
3  |  Oranges    |   2            |   Got 
1  |  Coconuts   |   1            |   Sto
```

Help would be appreciated, and an explanation please :)

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/be567/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/be567/7)

Code:

```
SELECT distinct r.ID,a.Name as ArticleName,
       sum(distinct a.Amount) as ArticlesAmount,
       substr(r.City,1,3) as ToCityName 
FROM Reservations r 
INNER JOIN Articles a 
      on r.Id = a.ReservationId 
WHERE  a.Name <> '' 
GROUP BY ToCityName,a.ArticleId,a.Name 
ORDER BY ToCityName ASC
```

You want to ensure you sum the amount by the distinct number of times it appears per group.

Answer (score 1):

I had added Articles again to select requested rows again... here is query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.ID,
    a.`Name` AS ArticleName,
    Articles.Amount,
    substr(r.City, 1, 3) AS ToCityName
FROM
    Reservations r
INNER JOIN Articles a ON r.Id = a.ReservationId
INNER JOIN Articles ON a.ReservationId = Articles.ReservationId
AND a.ArticleId = Articles.ArticleId
WHERE
    a. NAME <> ''
GROUP BY
    ToCityName,
    a.ArticleId,
    a. NAME
ORDER BY
    ToCityName ASC
```